# ActiveRecord in production mode without rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, production-environment

I want to use activerecord without rails. I know that in rails we can use the production mode as `RAILS_ENV=production` but how do I use production mode in activerecord without rails?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create one YML file or any properties file to store database properties for each of your environment.
2. While starting your non-rails app, start with a environment variable like `APP_ENV=production`
3. In your application code, use this environment variable & read the appropriate file and pass to ActiveRecord

> ```
> environment = ENV['APP_ENV'] || 'development'
> puts "Connecting to #{environment} database"
> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection YAML.load_file(config)[environment]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The way you connect to your database is up to you, you just have to supply the credentials. If you want to implement something like `config/database.yml` without Rails you will have to do it yourself, and you can use an environment variable of your choice to specify which key in the file to read.